# Questions using Base64 and remote querys into remote Database.. (high waiting time with bigger images???)

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, base64

i have a image of 5Kb, when i transform it into Base64 string and i upload to my remote database, the remote INSERT query needs only a few secs

but.. i have a image of 100Kb, when i transform it into Base64 string and i upload to my remote database, the remote INSERT query needs a lot of seconds to be executed

why?

it is because the Base64 String needs 100KB of space like the non encoded image?

there is a way to solve these waiting times?

**MORE INFO:** im using PHP+JSOn to connect to mysql remote database.

Oded sugested me to not using Base64 and to use BLOB and not LONGTEXT. **But.... ¿how to use BLOB with JSON+PHP? i dont know it** as i know, JSON+PHP needs to receive and send Strings, and BLOB is not a String

thanks

EDIT 2:

this is the code where it takes a looot time waiting (it waits in the line: `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {` , it is waiting on `reader.readLine()`  )

this code gets one user from the remote database, it takes a loooooot of time to show the user on my app

```
public Friend RetrieveOneUser(String email)
{

    Friend friend=null;

    String result = "";
    //the parameter data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));

    //http post
    InputStream is=null;
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.BaseURL + this.GetOneUser_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    friend=new Friend(json_data.getString("email"),json_data.getString("password"), json_data.getString("fullName"), json_data.getString("mobilePhone"), json_data.getString("mobileOperatingSystem"),"",json_data.getString("photo"));
            }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return friend;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store the image directly as a [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object)?

All the conversion accomplishes is delays and extra CPU time.

---

Update:

Now that we know *why* base64 is required (since JSON can't transfer binary data), I amend my answer.

You need to check *why* this is taking a long time. Is it network transfer? Is it the database? Once you know the answer, we can start looking at a solution.

Comment: how to do it? BLOB stores string ?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - No. BLOBs store _binary_ data, such as the image data itself. If you tell us what database you are using, an appropriate method can be suggested.

Comment: is not the same? read this:  10.4.3. The BLOB and TEXT Types

A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold. The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT. These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same maximum lengths and storage requirements. See Section 10.5, “Data Type Storage Requirements”.

Comment: i am using MYSQL for the remote database, and SQLite for the local database (copy of the remote)

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - That's my point. You are doing unnecessary work. Why convert to Base64 to begin with?

Comment: also i connect to the remote database with JSON, then, because this, i am sending the images as a String with Base64, if BLOB can't accept strings then i can't use BLOB

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - You should really post all of the above as an edit to your question. If you want useful answers, you should provide as much relevant data in the question.

Comment: what you need to be posted? what part of my app you want?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - I mean your comments. The use of both MySQL and SQLite, usage of JSON, why you _must_ use base64 for images and why BLOBs are not suitable.

Comment: because JSON+PHP needs to use Strings as parameters, and BLOB is binary, not string. how to use BLOB with JSON+PHP ?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - **please edit your question**. Add the detail there. It is hidden in comments and other people will not see it.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - And you still didn't explain in your edit, why base64 is a must.

Comment: explained now, check it please, can you help me?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - That doesn't tell us if the problem is with the network or the database.

Answer (score 1):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is 6-bit encoding: it requires 4 characters (4 bytes) to transmit 3 bytes of an image.  So storing a 100kb image in Base64 takes up 133kb worth of space.

You haven't said which database you're using, but not all databases perform well if you store more than 8kb per row.